# Error: No template found for MyAppComponent

Tags: angularjs

I've followed the [Angular 2 Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html) guide but get the following error:

> Error during instantiation of Token(AppView)!. ORIGINAL ERROR: Error:
>   No template found for MyAppComponent

This is the relevant code:

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser'
// Note I've changed Template to View here as I think it is a typo

....

@View({
  template: '<h1>Hello {{ name }}</h1>'
})

....
```

Following Duncan Booth's suggestion here http://blog.ionic.io/angular-2-series-introduction/ I made the changes below and everything works:

```
import {Component, Template} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';

....

@Template({
    inline: "<h1>Hello {{ name }}</h1>"
})

....
```

But yesimahuman's comment at the same link mentions that "View is the new syntax" which does seem to be the case as is shown in the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MRz2i7sjupzxERPAa3SF?p=preview) from the [Angular 2 Step by Step Guide](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/guide/setup.html).

So why is the Quickstart code throwing an error and what is the correct fix?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to check this out

```
import {Component, Template, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app'
})
@Template({
    inline: '<h1>Hello {{ name }}</h2>'
})

class MyAppComponent {
    constructor() {
        this.name = 'Alice';
    }
}

bootstrap(MyAppComponent);
```

Comment: In my question I've deliberately only shown the relevant code and I also say that View and **not** Template is the new syntax.

Comment: I completely understand what you said.. because it's what it is in the docs.... I do not know why it is not working for now

Answer (score 0):

And just to clarify: if you need to include some directives, you should do it this way:

```
import {Component, Template, View, CSSClass, NgFor, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';

// Component annotations ..
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app'
})
@Template({
    url: 'templates/layout.html'
})
@View({
    directives: [CSSClass, NgFor]
})
```

and then in the code you can use the [class], *ng-for, etc :)